# How do I create a Liquid tag with a for-loop?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

So, I'd like to create an .rb plugin for a Jekyll theme to be able to use the following Liquid syntax in .md files:

`{% tab caption %}`

which, when building a webpage from an .md file, should convert into:

`<p><b>Tab. X.</b> Caption</p>`

where X is the counting number of each particular `{% tab caption %}` tag in the document;
caption is the value for a key from a predefined hash, where the key matches the `caption` in the tag.

Say, I have the following code in .md:

```
The table below summarizes diagram symbols.

{% tab diagram %}

The table below presents the configuration options.

{% tab config %}
```

Which should return:

```
The table below summarizes diagram symbols.
<p><b>Tab. 1.</b> Diagram designations.</p>
The table below presents the configuration options.
<p><b>Tab. 2.</b> Configuration options.</p>
```

I've figured out value retrieval from hash quite easily; however, I can't figure out how to do the numbering. I assume I could for-loop through an array of the occurrences of this particular tag; however, I haven't managed to successfully google making such an array in the first place.

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out how to do what I wanted. It did not require any looping after all:

```
module Jekyll
    class TabHandler < Liquid::Tag
        @@count = 1

        def initialize(name, input, tokens)
            super
            @input = input
        end

        def render(context)
            modulename = context["modulename"].to_s
            dictionary = { "io " => "I/O specifications for " + modulename,
                "se " => modulename + " signal exchange",
                "diagram " => "Diagram designations" }
            if dictionary.has_key?(@input)
                output = "<p><b>Tab. " + @@count.to_s + ".</b> " + dictionary.fetch(@input) + ".</p>"
                @@count += 1
            else
                output = "<p><b>Tab. " + @@count.to_s + ".</b> " + @input + ".</p>"
                @@count += 1
            end
            return output
        end
    end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('tab', Jekyll::TabHandler)
```